# Are there any valid circumstances where foo=foo makes sense?

Tags: c#, refactoring, legacy

Cleaning a handful of warnings on a `C#` project I have inherited, I found this code snippet:

```
private bool _WriteValue(object FieldValue,..,..)
  ...
  if(MultipFactor!=1)
     FieldValue=((double)FieldValue)*MultipFactor;
  else
    FieldValue=FieldValue;
```

I've obviously burninated the `else` block without thinking too much, just wondering why the previous programmer has left that part.

- Was it just too lazy to delete it?
- Was it a courtesy for some future programmers to save some typing in case of specific changes?
- Is it hiding something dangerous?

In your opinion, are there any valid circumstances where `foo=foo` makes sense?

---

Some more details on the `_WriteValue` method:

The `_WriteValue` method is wrapped into different overloaded `WriteValue` methods that pass to the `object FieldValue` parameter, values of the following types: `int`, `long`, `string` and `Datetime`.

Comment: Does Fieldvalue's property setter have any side-effects?

Comment: If it was me I'd just get rid of the `if` and do the multiply every time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `FieldValue` is a property, the `set` operator could trigger some code, so a self-assignment could make sense in such a case?!

An example would be:

```
public string FieldValue
{
    get
    {
        return _fieldValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _fieldValue = value;
        Trace.WriteLine( string.Format("Received value '{0}'.", value ) );
    }
}
```

*(My answer was given before the poster added the information that `FieldValue` actually is a method parameter, not a property as I assumed first)*

Comment: But that opens a can of worms, side-effects in properties, whoa! And it would still make no sense to anybody reading it without knowledge of what those side-effects are.

Comment: @Mr. Yes, I agree, I was just guessing for a usage scenario :-)

Comment: @systempuntoout Sure. Please note that my response was to your article, before you added the information that `FieldValue` is actually a method parameter and not a property as I assumed first.

Answer (score 2):

There are some bad programmers, and they usually leave some garbage behind...

Answer (score 1):

If there was a getter or a setter behind `FieldValue` then it could have side effects. For example:

```
private double myFieldValue;

public double FieldValue
{
    get { return myFieldValue; }
    set { myFieldValue = value; ReformatSystemVolume(); }
}
```

It's exceedingly bad practice to have a getter with side-effects. However, it is very common to have setters wide side-effects, although less common for those side-effects to be as drastic as in my example!

Answer (score 1):

The programmer was probably unaware of the existence of conditional breakpoints and leveraged that statement as a location to place a breakpoint that triggered conditionally.

<sub>Just to make it clear, I'm not saying that this is a good idea, but it's a trick in environments without conditional breakpoints.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can define `operator=` to do anything you want :)

Comment: In C# you can't, at least not for the assignment operator. In C# only unary, binary and relational operators can be overloaded.

Comment: Where does C++ come into this question?

Comment: Maybe the code was ported from C++, and hence was copied over from there originally where the = operator was overloaded.  So perhaps functionality is actually broken if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are some low-level hardware situations where setting the value has (desirable) side effects that can't be invoked other ways.  It's stupid, but beyond the scope of programmers to fix.  I've only seen this situation in bare C code, so I'm sure that's not why you're seeing this in C# code, but it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is a terrific (and all-too-common) example of things you should comment: anything where the "obvious" "fix" will actually break things.  Make sure you learn from your frustrations!

Comment: are you suggesting to comment that I have removed the `else` block?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to whoever wrote that in the first place, or if you find out a legimiate reason for it to be there. My point was that if you ever do something similar, remember this episode and spare your coworkers or future self the same pain!